# node js postgres assign value to variable outside scope of then

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have to compare few rows derived from potgres with data derived from the dynamo DB. problem is in both cases i have to iterate over data & unless i can assign the value to a variable i will have to query the same data again from either one of two databases.

```
    function postgressdata(sql){
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          client_postgres.query(sql, (err, res) => {
             resolve(res);

           });
       });
    }
```

```
let get_creatives =  postgressdata(sql);
get_creatives.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // prints the result
  let new_result = result;
}
console.log(new_result) // does not print result
```

How Can I assign the data to a variable here & use it anywhere?
I am a newbie to NODEJS so pardon me if I am asking silly question.

Comment: The `then` of a Promise is call asynchronous, so the `console.log` is executed before the callback of `then` is. You have to move the `console.log` inside of the `then` (even if you would define `new_result` outside of it.)

Answer (score 0):

> Nodejs is non-blocking.

so when this block of code runs

```
let get_creatives =  postgressdata(sql);
get_creatives.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // prints the result
  let new_result = result;
}
console.log(new_result) // does not print result
```

what will happen is you will get nothing printed first because `.then()` will be called when the promise is resolved so this line

`console.log(new_result) // does not print result`

will be executed first which doesn't have the value yet obviously.

after that when the promise is resolved `.then` will be called and your value will be set.

now how to solve this?
I am assuming you're sending the value back to the callee so you can either use the `async/await` structure or you can use a callback, depending on how you need the value.

Comment: I tried the `async/await` method but with no luck. It would be great if you could help how can I achieve this with `async/await`. my requirement is just to have the SQL data in a variable which is calling the function. In my example "get_creatives"

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep a reference to the promise as your cache. A promise in JavaScript represents the result of an async operation, not the operation itself.

If you have something like:

```
async function runQuery() {
  const result = await db.query(sql`SELECT * FROM creatives;`);
  console.log('ran query');
  return result;
}

const creativesPromise = runQuery();
async function useResult() {
  console.log(await creativesPromise);
}
useResult();
useResult();
useResult();
```

even though we use the resulting list of creatives three times, "ran query" will only get logged once. Every use of the query results will need to be async, because you never know whether the query has finished running when you request the data, but the query will only be run once.

Comment: Still the same output : Promise { <pending> } . I know how to resolve this but it doesn't serve my purpose as I would have write all my code inside that promise resolve THEN statement.

Comment: Yes, that’s how JavaScript works. All async code must either be in an async function, or use .then.